# How to fix "initial_lr not specified when resuming optimizer" error for scheduler?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, scheduler

In PyTorch I have configured SGD like this:

```
sgd_config = {
    'params' : net.parameters(),
    'lr' : 1e-7,
    'weight_decay' : 5e-4,
    'momentum' : 0.9
}
optimizer = SGD(**sgd_config)
```

My requirements are:

- Total epochs are 100
- Every 30 epochs learning rate is decreased by a factor of 10
- Decreasing learning rate will stop at 60 epochs

So for 100 epochs I will get two times a decrease of `0.1` of my learning rate.

I read about learning rate scheduler, available in `torch.optim.lr_scheduler` so I decided to try using that instead of manually adjusting the learning rate:

```
scheduler = lr_scheduler.StepLR(optimizer, step_size=30, last_epoch=60, gamma=0.1)
```

However I am getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Projects\network\network_full.py", line 370, in <module>
    scheduler = lr_scheduler.StepLR(optimizer, step_size=30, last_epoch=90, gamma=0.1)
  File "D:\env\test\lib\site-packages\torch\optim\lr_scheduler.py", line 367, in __init__
    super(StepLR, self).__init__(optimizer, last_epoch, verbose)
  File "D:\env\test\lib\site-packages\torch\optim\lr_scheduler.py", line 39, in __init__
    raise KeyError("param 'initial_lr' is not specified "
KeyError: "param 'initial_lr' is not specified in param_groups[0] when resuming an optimizer"
```

I read a post [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/a-problem-occured-when-resuming-an-optimizer/28822) and I still don't get how I would use the scheduler for my scenario. Maybe I am just not understanding the definition of `last_epoch` given that the [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.optim.lr_scheduler.StepLR.html#torch.optim.lr_scheduler.StepLR) is very brief on this parameter:

> **last_epoch** (*int*) – The index of last epoch. Default: `-1`.

Since the argument is made available to the user and there is no explicit prohibition on using a scheduler for less epochs than the optimizer itself, I am starting to think it's a bug.

Answer (score 4):

`last_epoch` must be -1 unless you are resuming the training.
If you are attempting to resume the training, the problem is you created scheduler before loading the optimizer params.

Correct procedure to resume:

```
    sgd_config = {
        'params' : net.parameters(),
        'lr' : 1e-7,
        'weight_decay' : 5e-4,
        'momentum' : 0.9
    }
    optimizer = SGD(**sgd_config)
    optimizer.load_state_dict(torch.load('your_save_optimizer_params.pt'))
    scheduler = lr_scheduler.StepLR(optimizer, step_size=30, gamma=0.1, last_epoch=50)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have misunderstood the last_epoch argument and you are not using the correct learning rate scheduler for your requirements.

This should work:

```
optim.lr_scheduler.MultiStepLR(optimizer, [0, 30, 60], gamma=0.1, last_epoch=args.current_epoch - 1)
```

The last_epoch argument makes sure to use the correct LR when resuming training. It defaults to -1, so the epoch before epoch 0.

Answer (score 0):

A: You have to specify last_epoch=60 as a separate command, in diff format:

```
<< scheduler = lr_scheduler.StepLR(optimizer, step_size=30, last_epoch=60, gamma=0.1)
```

---

```
>> scheduler = lr_scheduler.StepLR(optimizer, step_size=30, gamma=0.1)
>> scheduler.last_epoch = 60
```

Use this to inspect scheduler values:

```
print(scheduler.state_dict())
```

{'step_size': 30, 'gamma': 0.1, 'base_lrs': [0.0002], 'last_epoch': 4, '_step_count': 5, 'verbose': False, '_get_lr_called_within_step': False, '_last_lr': [0.0002]}

Answer (score 0):

```
 sgd_config = {
    'params' : net.parameters(),
    **'initial_lr': 1e-7**,
    'lr' : 1e-7,
    'weight_decay' : 5e-4,
    'momentum' : 0.9
}
optimizer = SGD(**sgd_config)
```